# Python counter values and boolean all() not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, boolean-expression

This has really got me stumped. I have a bunch of Counters, and I want to check if all of the values meet a certain condition. Using `all()` makes sense. So I set it up like so:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_counter = Counter(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> my_counter
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2})
```

`all()` works on iterables, `Counter.values()` returns an iterable, the individual values are integers, and yet:

```
>>> all(my_counter.values())>1
False
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `all(my_counter.values())` gives `False` if any value is 0, `True` otherwise. Then that boolean is compared to > 1, which is always `False`.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I had checked help() but not the actual docs. The docs made it very clear. I just moved the logic inside a comprehension in all() and it worked.

Comment: For element-wise comparison, consider `numpy` :) For example, `numpy.array([1, 5, 3, 7]) > 4` yields `array([False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and check this code. The last line does what you intend to do.
`all(my_counter.values())` tells us if all the values within the counter are iterable. Check https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/all

```
#python 3.5.2
from collections import Counter
my_counter = Counter(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
for row in ((my_counter.values())):
    print(row)
print(all(i > 1 for i in my_counter.values()))
```

Comment: Yup, that's basically it. I didn't need a print statement, but a comprehension inside all() works.

Answer (score 0):

`all` essentially just does:

```
def all(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        if not item:
            return False
    return True
```

That means it will just check if all `values` are "truthy", in your case all values are `!= 0` so they are considered True and so:

```
>>> all(my_counter.values())
True
```

But `True` (which behaves like the integer `1`) is not `> 1` so the result will be `False`:

```
>>> all(my_counter.values()) > 1
False
```

What you want is to check if every value is greater than one, then you could either just use a self-written variant of `all`:

```
def all_greater_than_one(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        if item <= 1:
            return False
    return True

>>> all_greater_than_one(my_counter.values())
True
```

Or use a generator expression to "transform" the iterable passed to `all`:

```
>>> all(value > 1 for value in my_counter.values())
True
```

Note that you could also use a list-comprehension here instead of the generator expression:

```
>>> all([value > 1 for value in my_counter.values()])
True
```

Or some other way to transform it - I'm not recommending the following because the generator or comprehension is generally better, just to show some alternatives:

```
>>> all(map(lambda x: x > 1, my_counter.values()))
True
>>> all(map((1).__le__, my_counter.values()))  # avoid this, just here for entertainment.
True
```